# Delete Sharepoint files using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, recycle-bin, sharepoint-2016

I want to delete files in Sharepoint 2016 from its recycle bin.
I am able to delete files from my folder using requests.delete. However, not able to do the same from recycle bin.

Can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this endpoint:

```
POST http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/RecycleBin(recyclebinitemid)/deleteObject()
```

reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246911(v=office.15)

Comment: This is a Javascript object. How to achieve this via Python?

Comment: You could try to use python send http request.

Comment: So I am running something like this: x = requests.post("https://example.net/sites/AdminRecycleBin.aspx/deleteObject()")      This is returning 200 code but it aint emptying the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I have been able to achieve this via shareplum.

```
cred = HttpNtlmAuth(username,password)
site = Site("sharepointsiteurl",version=Version.v365,auth=cred)
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/My Folder')
folder.delete_file('MyFile.csv')
```

This deletion is apparently deleting file completely. Neither there on Recycle bin nor on Second stage recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Powershell script? There is a Sharepoint function for that

Comment: Yes, I came across that. However, I wanted to only achieve this via python in unix as my connecting python script is also on unix server.